# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml

Estoy aprendiendo lo básico de Python con el libro "Python Programming Fundamentals" y tengo un problema con un error que no doy solucinado.

Estoy usando el debbuger Wing 101 8, y quería parsear el siguiente código XML:

```
<? xml version =" 1 . 0 " encoding =" UTF -8 " standalone =" no " ? >
< GraphicsCommands >
< Command color =" #804000 " > BeginFill </ Command >
< Command x=" 299.0 " y=" -45.0 " width =" 1 . 0 "
color =" #804000 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" 302.0 " y=" -297.0 " width =" 1.0 "
color =" #804000 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" -301.0 " y=" -298.0 " width =" 1.0 "
color =" #804000 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" -300.0 " y=" -53.0 " width =" 1 . 0 "
color =" #804000 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command > EndFill </ Command >
< Command color =" #004080 " > BeginFill </ Command >
< Command x=" -300.0 " y=" 300.0 " width =" 1.0 "
color =" #004080 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" 299.0 " y=" 299.0 " width =" 1 . 0 "
color =" #004080 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" 300.0 " y=" -45.0 " width =" 1 . 0 "
color =" #004080 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command > EndFill </ Command >
< Command > PenUp </ Command >
< Command x=" 0 . 0 " y=" 0 . 0 " width =" 1 . 0 "
color =" #000000 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command > PenDown </ Command >
< Command radius =" 10.0 " width =" 10 "
color ="# ffffff " > Circle </ Command >
< Command radius =" 20.0 " width =" 10 "
color ="# ff0080 " > Circle </ Command >
< Command x=" 2 . 0 " y=" -4.0 " width =" 10.0 "
color ="# ff0080 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" 2 . 0 " y=" -5.0 " width =" 10.0 "
color ="# ff0080 " >GoTo </ Command >
< Command x=" 2 . 0 " y=" -6.0 " width =" 10.0 "
color ="# ff0080 " >GoTo </ Command >
</ GraphicsCommands >
```

Para ello he usado el siguiente código:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('flowerandbg.xml')
```

Y tras ejecutar el programa he obtenido el siguiente error:

```
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate ensucio.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ARCHIVOS APRENDIZAJE PYTHON\ensucio.py", line 3, in <module>
    pass
  File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1988, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 911, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, False)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2
```

He estado mirando las funciones de las librerías que usa y no entiendo donde está el problema puesto que son librerias que ya vienen preinstaladas con Python y no simplemento he querido parsear un archivo que tengo guardado.
Cuando me salta el error se abre la librería "expatbilder.py" y me identifica el error en la siguiente línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a encontrar el porqué surge este error?

A continuación muestro una foto de como valido en xmlvalidation.com el código XML y en la siguiente el mismo error que se genera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El XML que le estas intentando pasar esta hecho unos zorros lleno de espacios innecesarios por todas partes. Primero valida el XML en esta web:  https://www.xmlvalidation.com/, y cuando alli te diga que es válido inténtalo con python

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias, eso era algo que sin duda estaba mal. De todas formas sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Acabo de editar la publicación para poner una foto en la que se ve como valido en (xmlvalidation.com) el código y como al ejecutarlo me salta una librería de las que usa y se ve en rojo el error que se genera. ¿me puedes echar un cable?

Comment: Ahi ya no te puedo ayudar, el python no es lo mio :-(  De todos modos, si tienes el XML arreglado sustituye el de la pregunta por el bueno, para que no te lo pidan de nuevo.